# How to host a site a website without WWW in Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, subdomain

I recently hosted a site in google cloud. For that, I've created a bucket named `www.mydomain.com` And I've followed all the steps and the website is working fine if I put URL like `www.mydomain.com` but not when I put `mydomain.com` without `www`. What is the best way to achieve this? How can I make the URL `mydomain.com` work?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This setting has to be made on your domain registration service, not on Google Storage side.

In your DNS settings, you will have to redirect `domain.com` to `www.domain.com`. Note that being able to do this will depend on your provider.

If that is not an option you could use a Compute Engine instance free tier or App Engine to redirect the requests from yourdomain.com to www.yourdomain.com

---

Also, [CDN is used for caching content](http://%20https://cloud.google.com/cdn/) so I don't think you have your CNAME there, maybe you are referring to Cloud DNS?
If that is the case, you will not be able to do the redirect just using Cloud DNS so you will have to use one of the other options

Comment: Am  maintaining my CDN in google cloud but I see there is no option to create a CNAME without www.